# Generate bearer token for google cloud function - Java

Tags: google-cloud-functions, serverless

I'm trying to connect to cloud function such as https://us-west1-<>.cloudfunctions.net from java, and I'm trying to generate the bearer token for this function using a code as follows:

```
String audience = https://<projectname>-<region>-<projectid>.cloudfunctions.net/<myFunction>;

GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials
                .getApplicationDefault()
                .createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));

IdTokenCredentials tokenCredential =
                IdTokenCredentials.newBuilder()
                    .setIdTokenProvider((IdTokenProvider) credentials)
                    .setTargetAudience(audience)
                    .build();
        
tokenCredential.refresh();
        
String token = tokenCredential.getIdToken().getTokenValue();
```

When I run the application the token is generated. But if I take the token and put this on postman, the server returns an 401 error: **401 Unauthorized**.

if I use the GCP command "gcloud auth print-identity-token" in GCP cloud shell terminal and use this token in postman, the cloud function invocation is successful.

The Json file used to get the credentials is similar to this:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "<project_id>",
  "private_key_id": "<private_key_id>",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----------END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "aaa@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "<client_id>",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/<principle>"
}
```

Please help me in figuring out how to generate a bearer token in java to invoke a google cloud function.

Thanks

Comment: With `gcloud auth print...` you use the `gcloud auth login` credential, dedicated to the GCLOUD CLI. When you use code, you use ADC: either the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var if set, or the credential of the command `gcloud auth application-default login`. Check your credentials and try again.

Comment: Thank you @guillaumeblaquiere for the suggestion. My issue was due to the incorrect value I was using for the audience. It fixed when I gave correct audience value. Please see my answer for the audience value I gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue got fixed when I used the correct audience value as below.

https://**function-url**/projects/**project-id**/locations/**region**/functions/**function-name**

In the above URI, replace function-url, project-id, region, and function-name with your values.

Following is the working code.

```
public String getAccessToken(String audience) throws IOException {
        
        InputStream resource = new ClassPathResource(
                  "gcp/service-account.json").getInputStream();
        
        GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials
                 .fromStream(resource)
                 .createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
        
        credentials.refreshAccessToken();
        
        IdTokenCredentials tokenCredential =
                IdTokenCredentials.newBuilder()
                    .setIdTokenProvider((IdTokenProvider) credentials)
                    .setTargetAudience(audience)
                    .build();
                
        tokenCredential.refresh();
        
        return tokenCredential.getIdToken().getTokenValue();
      }
```

In the above code,

1. The "gcp/service-account.json" is the path of my service account json file. It is under the src/main/resources folder (i.e. classpath) in my spring-boot project.
2. The `credentials.refreshAccessToken();` and `tokenCredential.refresh();` might not be needed. I did not try removing these. Will try when get time.

Hope it helps guys!! Since I could not find much help on the "audience" value, so it took me some time to figure out the correct value by trial and error.

Comment: in case i don't have the file under src main resources and i use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS , how would you load it ? it also is used like : spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location: file:${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}

Comment: @TiagoMedici, then use below code to load.  

```GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials
       .getApplicationDefault()
       .createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));```

Comment: i m using a service account to invoke a firebase cloud functions and it throws : Firebase ID token has incorrect "aud" (audience) claim, Make sure the ID token comes from the same Firebase project as the service account used to authenticate this SDK. looks i need the firebase token which is different from IdTokenCredentials

Comment: I'm not sure how this is working for you. This looks like it only generates a refresh token and not an access token?